# SQLAlchemy relations parent to child from multiple fields

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

What is the better way to point multiple relations from parent object to child from different fields.
The main problem is consistency while deleting of objects.
For example we have entities like this:
[image]

Customer is independent entity, but CustomerAddress and CustomerSettings doesn't exist without Customer.

So I have to gurantee CustomerSettings and CustomerAddress will be deleted, when Customer is deleted.

There is no problem with CustomerSettings, just `cascade` will do all the job, but CustomerAddress has no foreign key to Customer.

In SQL there should be 3 tables

1. Table `Customer`

   - Column `id` - primary key
   - Columns `name`, `surname`, `email` - just value columns
   - Column `shipping_address` - foreign key to `CustomerAddress.id`
   - Column `billing_address` - foreign key to `CustomerAddress.id`
2. Table `CustomerAddress`

   - Column `id` - primary key
   - Columns `city`, `street`, `house`, `postal_code` - just value columns
3. Table `CustomerSettings`

   - Column `id` - primary key
   - Column `customer_id` - foreign key to `Customer.id`
   - Other columns - just value columns

SqlAlchemy snippet

```py
customer_table = Table(
    'customer',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True),
    Column('name', String, index=True),
    Column('surname', String, index=True),
    Column('email', String, index=True),
    Column(
        'shipping_address',
        ForeignKey('customer_address.id', name='fk_customer_address_id'),
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
    ),
    Column(
        'billing_address',
        ForeignKey('customer_address.id', name='fk_customer_address'),
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
    ),
)

customer_address_table = Table(
    'customer_address',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True),
    Column('city', String, index=True),
    Column('street', String, index=True),
    Column('house', String, index=True),
    Column('postal_code', Integer, index=True),
)

customer_settings_table = Table(
    'customer_settings',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True),
    Column('push_notification', Boolean),
    Column('email_notification', Boolean),
    Column('subscription_info', String, index=True),
    Column(
        'customer_id',
        ForeignKey('customer.id', name='fk_customer_id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
    ),
)


class Customer(Base):
    __table__ = customer_table
    
    shipping_address: RelationshipProperty = relationship(
        CustomerAddress,
        uselist=False,
        cascade='all, delete',
    )
    
    billing_address: RelationshipProperty = relationship(
        CustomerAddress,
        uselist=False,
    )
    
    settings: RelationshipProperty = relationship(
        CustomerSettings,
        uselist=False,
    )

class CustomerAddress(Base):
    __table__ = customer_address_table

class CustomerSettings(Base):
    __table__ = customer_settings_table
```

Questions:

1. How can I guarantee CustomerAddress to be deleted with Customer
2. Is there an "out of the box" way to implement this with SQLAlchemy
3. May be there is better way to organize SQL tables

We tried assosiation table, but in this case both foreign keys should go from assosiation table and it not helps with deleting.
Main idea now is to add foreign key to `customer_address` table with not null constraint, ot should lead to consistent deleting, but i'm not sure how this cross foreign keys should be implemented using SQLAlchemy